# Can you split stacks of items?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Is it possible to split stacks of items from an initial stack?

Sometimes when I have multiple of an item, I'd like to figure out a base sell price by just offering 1 to Timmy (or Tommy?) and from there gauge what items are more effective to sell for.

Often times however I can't seem to find an option to split a stack of items from an initial stack. Sometimes I need to sell weeds for a Nook Miles challenge but also need to keep some weeds for crafting furniture items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be way to easily split stacks into stacks of more than 1. However, it is pretty easy to take 1 item of your stack. Simply press <kbd>A</kbd> on a stack in your inventory, and choose "Grab 1". It will put the single item in an empty inventory space.

If you're looking to split a stack of 30 into two stacks of, say, 15 each, you're going to have to do it the way I described above. It's very tedious.

Finally, you can use a similar way to split items by dropping them on the ground and picking them up, one by one.